# Method that gets the initials of a person

Tags: java, eclipse

I've made a class that can create persons (First, middle and last names + birthday) and I've made a method that gets the initials of the person. The method can be seen below:

```
public String getInit() {
        return "" + firstName.charAt(0) + middleName.charAt(0)
            + lastName.charAt(0);
        }
```

however i have since made a second constructor for people without middle names and I want the method to be able to create initials for them, but I am not sure how to make the method ignore the middle name for those who does not have any.

Its in java and I'm pretty new to programming so any help would be much appreciated
EDIT: added code as text

Comment: Add code as Text not as link to an image

Comment: I can see the link? weird

Comment: We can see the link too, but nobody wants to click a link in a new tab to read code that should be text copy and pasted into the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the `middleName` is `null`, if not take the first character else nothing

```
return firstName.charAt(0)+ (middleName == null? "" :middleName.char(0))+lastnName.charAt(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!